# console2 - how to edit config file, what name/location?

Tags: console2

Have mistakenly set the path and command sequence for cygwin bash.  Invoking it now results in path error, so would like to edit the run code to fix it.  Where is that bugger?  Had set preferences to save to a config file.

Answer (score 3):

The config file is in Users\\AppData\Roaming\Console\console.xml

just set the shell="" and restart the console.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was:

```
%AppData%\Console\console.xml
```